# Do all end events end the whole process?

Tags: bpmn

In the following example, if arriving at "dealer reminded", will this end the whole process? Since the branch is triggered by a non-interrupting event, we could also arrive at "order confirmed".

I hope it works the way that both end events must be reached (assuming "answer a bit late" has been triggered), but in case of the interrupting event "answer overdue" I guess "order not deliverable" will terminate the whole process. Is this correct?

[image: BPMN diagram with non-interrupting event]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BPMN spec says (on p. 246) that "All the tokens that were generated within the Process MUST be consumed by an End Event before the Process has been completed". This means that the process ends when all parallel paths have completed, implying that both a "Dealer reminded" and an "Order confirmed" (or, alternatively, an "Order not available") end event must occur for completing a process according to your model.

Answer (score 3):

End events only end their respective branch. They "eat" the token, nothing else.

There is a different  element that deletes all tokens of its scope, therefore effectively ending it: the "terminate" end event.

So no, "order not deliverable" will not terminate the process and a token at "remind dealer" will remain there.